# How to prove equilaterity of triangle in these specific conditions?

Tags: geometry

We have rectangle ABCD and points E on the line segment BC and F one the line segment CD. The triangle AEF is equilateral. We have the point M in the centre of the line segment AF. How to prove that triangle BCM is equilateral without using trigonometric functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you also use a more relevant title which gives some insight in to the content of what you want to prove?

Comment: Title changed. Honestly, I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\hspace{100pt}$[image: equi_triag]

It's a hint, I provide no description by intention.
I hope it helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I'm wondering how did you generate that picture? With some kind of program?

Comment: @Jantomedes Yep, [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

Answer (score 1):

M is the midpoint of AF.so angle EMF=angle AME= 90[as AEF is equilateral]. now see angle ECF =90.SO QUADRILATERAL EMFC Is cyclic. so angle MCE = angle MFE = 60. similarly QUADRILATERAL EMAB IS CYCLIC. SO ANGLE MBE = ANGLE EAM =60. so in triangle BMC angle = angle BCM =60 .SO triangle BCM IS EQUILATERAL.

1. [image]

Comment: Nice one krishan..